# Powershell Script for Find and replace a string with servername

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to do below tasks -

1. Open D:...\123.xml
2. Find `<domain>.domainname.com</domain>`
3. Replace `<domain>'$serverlist'.domain.com</domain>`
4. Loop 1-3 steps with server list which is located at C:\Temp\servers.txt

when I run below code I'm getting an error, any help would be appreciated

Script -

```
$serverlist="C:\Temp\servers.txt"

get-content -Path $serverlist | 
ForEach-Object {

$file = 'D:\...\123.xml'
$find = '  <domain>.domainname.com</domain>'
$replace = ' <domain>'$serverlist'.domain.com</domain>'

(Get-Content $file).replace($find, $replace) | Set-Content $file

}
```

Comment: What is the error? `$replace = ' <domain>'$serverlist'.domain.com</domain>'` should be `$replace = '"<domain>$serverlist.domain.com</domain>"`

Comment: Error - At C:\temp\123.ps1:8 char:24
+ $replace = ' <domain>"'$serverlist'".domain.com</domain>'
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '$serverlist'".domain.com</domain>'' in expression or statement.
At C:\temp\123.ps1:8 char:35
+ $replace = ' <domain>"'$serverlist'".domain.com</domain>'
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token ''".domain.com</domain>'' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: That is exactly what my comment pointed out. Try my first comment and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here.

1. Your replacement string is malformed.

   $replace = ' '$serverlist'.domain.com'

should be

```
$replace = " <domain>$($serverlist).domain.com</domain>"
```

PowerShell will not implicitly concatenate the three different string values you put in your foreach loop. You could also do:

```
$replace = ' <domain>' + $serverlist + '.domain.com</domain>'
```

2. You can also set your static variables outside of your foreach loop. $file and $find don't change throughout any of the loops of your code.
3. It's a little unclear what you're trying to do. If you're getting the same file each time, and replacing all the instances of '  .domainname.com', then there won't be any more of that string to find when you move on to the next servername in the list. Do you also have a list of files you are running this on? In a particular order? Should part of the replacement string match something that has to do with the server name?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.. when I ran the script with updating $replace command now it is printing C:\Temp\servers.txt.domain name.com

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. You are opening one xml file and replacing the same string. Your code will open the xml file, replace the domain string, and then try again for the other servers but you've already replaced the string you're looking for. Can you be more specific with the scenario? It doesn't really make sense in the way it's currently laid out.

Comment: I have one xml file which is available in many servers. I need to replace the domain name from .domainnam.com to servername.domainname.com once I'll get success to 1 server I want to update same to remote servers as well. also my problem is .domainname.com is there in 3 other places in xml file but I need to change this 1 string.

Comment: Calling Get-Content does not open up the .xml file on that server. It only creates an array of values that were located in the .txt file. It's just like doing $serverNames = @('server1','server2','server3'). Is it actually the same xml file? Or is it a similar file with the same name on each server?